# Call a method inside a java-script class from another method inside the same class

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make my own class so maintaining could be a lot easier but i have problem, Here is my code :

```
var SonalScript = function() {
console.log('instance created');
    this.AjaxCall = function(url,data){
      $.post(url,data,function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
          });
}

this.Switches = function(ElemIdentifier) {
    $(ElemIdentifier).bootstrapSwitch();
    $(ElemIdentifier).on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
        //  console.log( $(this).get('name'));
        var ModuleName = $(this).attr("name");
        var name = $(this).data("name") ;
        var BtnValue = $(this).data("value") ;
        var url = $(this).data("addr") ;
        var BtnResult = '';
        if (state) {
        // data-addr
        // data-name
        // data-value
        // result = True Or False
        BtnResult = 'True';
        //  alert('Enabling : ' + ModuleName );

        } else {
         BtnResult = 'False';
        //  alert('Disabling : ' + ModuleName);
        }

      //  alert(result);

        var data = { name:BtnValue , result : BtnResult };
        console.log(data);
        console.log(url);
        this.AjaxCall(url,data); // << Problem is exactly this line

    });
  }


};

 SonalUtil = new SonalScript();
```

When I'm trying to call: 
           this.AjaxCall(url,data); 
then i got this error in Console :

```
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

What do you think ? What makes the error ?

Comment: You're *not* calling `AjaxCall` from the `Switches` *method*, but from that `switchChange.bootstrapSwitch` callback *function*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can go about this, one is binding `this` to the callback, the other is putting `this` into closure context of the callback funtion. So the first method would be:

```
...
this.Switches = function(ElemIdentifier) {
    $(ElemIdentifier).bootstrapSwitch();
    $(ElemIdentifier).on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
        ...
    }.bind(this));
  }
...
```

And the second would be

```
....
var self = this;
$(ElemIdentifier).on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
        //  console.log( $(self).get('name'));
        var ModuleName = $(self).attr("name");
        var name = $(self).data("name") ;
        var BtnValue = $(self).data("value") ;
        var url = $(self).data("addr") ;
        var BtnResult = '';
        if (state) {
        // data-addr
        // data-name
        // data-value
        // result = True Or False
        BtnResult = 'True';
        //  alert('Enabling : ' + ModuleName );

        } else {
         BtnResult = 'False';
        //  alert('Disabling : ' + ModuleName);
        }

      //  alert(result);

        var data = { name:BtnValue , result : BtnResult };
        console.log(data);
        console.log(url);
        self.AjaxCall(url,data); // << Problem is exactly this line

    });
...
```

Comment: tank you , Second one is better . its working fine.